# asp.net mvc4 admin environment separate from public

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a new asp.net mvc4 web application which consist of a public environment and separate  an admin environment, now I'm wondering what is the best practice to do this.

I would like the the admins to login at mysite.com/admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to orginize like bluetoff has written - adding areas. But if your admin part is not very complex I prefere just to create seperate controller "Admin" and limit access to it with Attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
```

And in LogOn method add redirection to AdminController if user is in role "admin":

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "admin"))
                    {
                        return Redirect("Index", "Admin");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The paradigm which has worked best for me in the past is setting up an admin [area](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/a9P1010113-MVC-Areas-with-example.html).  Once you have the area this will enable you to clearly separate your admin functionality from the rest of your application.  ie `/admin/users /admin/yourentities`

To differentiate your admin area from the rest of your application you should set up user Roles and limit admin users based on roles.  This way you have one User type database table, one Roles table and you have simple, maintainable, and understandable structure.

To utilize the roles you can create a [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you can check the user role and limit access to only Admin Role users